# Angular 4 date-pipe, odd result

Tags: angular, date, datetime

I am using angular 4.1 and get very weird results when using the date pipe

the json:

```
TimeStamp:"2017-05-04T13:22:01"
```

the html

```
<div> {{log.TimeStamp | date:"y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}} </div>
```

and the result

```
2017-05-04 13:00:5/4/2017 1:22:01 PM:5/4/2017 1:22:01 PM
```

i have tried different formats, and

if i use this --> i get this

```
date:"HH"   -->     13:00

date: "mm:ss"  -->  5/4/2017 1:22:01 PM:5/4/2017 1:22:01 PM
```

that doesnt seem to match the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html#!#sts=Pipe)?

Comment: Everything looks right to me. https://plnkr.co/edit/gRxmGivbId8SjQdjItzz?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, i'll try 4.1.1 as well, and see if it helps

Comment: Unfortunatley not, so it must be something in my solution that messes it up.